# Error invoking chaincode using Node.js SDK [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectivityState' of undefined]

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

Failed to invoke successfully :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectivityState' of undefined
/opt/share/hyperledger/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js:355
            if(self._stream) state = self.*stream.call.channel*.getConnectivityState();
                                                                ^

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectivityState' of undefined
    at ClientDuplexStream.<anonymous> (/opt/share/hyperledger/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js:355:56)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/opt/share/hyperledger/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:236:12)
    at ClientDuplexStream._readsDone (/opt/share/hyperledger/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:201:8)
    at /opt/share/hyperledger/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:705:15
```

I am using latest version of pre-requisites as mentioned in below link:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/getting_started.html#install-prerequisites

Can anybody tell me where am i going wrong?

Comment: I am also having this issue, thought it was an issue with the port not forwarding correctly to the host, but I forwarded 7050, 7051, and 7053 manually on Oracle VM and still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is due to a new version of grpc released 3 days ago (v1.11.0). The version is controlled by fabric-client and it takes the latest available. You need to delete the grpc module and reinstall it with `npm install grpc@1.9.1`. This will fix the issue. Going forward you may need to have grpc fixed at 1.9.1 in your package.json until Hyperledger resolve this issue.

Reference:
https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/general?msg=FME6aDfnfMexWTm6g

Comment: I was having this issue but after downgrading to 1.9.1 I'm still unable to get past the "Writing your first application" tutorial, please let me know if you can. Or see my question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158509/event-hub-has-been-shutdown-on-fabric-writing-your-first-application

Comment: After downgrading to `grpc@1.9.1` this error was resolved for me. Simply hardcode `"grpc":"1.9.1"` in package.json and re-run `npm install` and `npm rebuild` just in case.

Comment: are you able to go through the "Writing your first application" section? This error was resolved for me but still can't get past a different error. I added my package-lock.json into my question if you are interested

Comment: changing "grpc":"1.9.1" in package.json doesn't work for me - did you have to do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

I commented these lines in `EventHub.js`.
It's required only for state log.
For example:

```
<br/>
<i>         var state = -1;<br/>
            //if(self._stream) state = self._stream.call.channel_.getConnectivityState();<br/>
            logger.debug('on.data - grpc stream state :%s',state);<br/>
</i><br/><br/>
```

it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still getting below error after commenting the line in **EventHub.js**

> Failed to invoke successfully :: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectivityState' of undefined

Previous detailed error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectivityState' of undefined
>       at ClientDuplexStream. (/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/EventHub.js:308:56)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at ClientDuplexStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
>       at ClientDuplexStream.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
>       at Object.onReceiveMessage (/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1302:19)
>       at InterceptingListener.recvMessageWithContext (/fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:629:19)
>       at /fabric-samples/fabcar/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:728:14

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5096693/dikshika-jain Please refer to my answer.https://stackoverflow.com/a/50153354/8169762

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue while building the web docker
edit package.json
add the line
 "dependencies": {
    "grpc" : "1.9.1",

build the docker again
issue the docker compose agin ! it works

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to connect the composer bna to IBM blockchain, and I tried out installing grpc 1.9.1.. and even 1.10.1.. I tried out like everything, and the only thing that worked was doing as Kataus suggested, I commented out the lines relate to the getConnectivity state, and it finally connected to the IBM blockchain network I had.