# Event Hub has been Shutdown on Fabric Writing your first Application

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am currently trying to run through the example first application for Hyperledger Fabric here -> http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/write_first_app.html

I am unable to get past calling `node invoke.js`

Originally I was getting the same error as this question [Error invoking chaincode using Node.js SDK [TypeError: Cannot read property 'getConnectivityState' of undefined]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50134379/error-invoking-chaincode-using-node-js-sdk-typeerror-cannot-read-property-get)

But after reverting to grpc@1.9.1 I get the following result:

[image]

I am able to do everything up to the `node query.js` method and that returns successfully but can't quite get past this.

Node version: 8.11.1

Docker Version:

[image]

fabric client section of package-lock.json

[image]
FYI: I am trying to run on Windows 10 mostly using the docker toolbox bash, or a separate git bash CLI.

Last piece of info!

Even though the invoke js command fails with the above error, I can see that the PUT command to couch db does go through and car10 has been successfully added.

[image]

If I check the docker logs for `peer0.org1.example.com` I see the following:

[image]

So did it actually work?

Comment: Have you ever saw the peer log?

Comment: Where is that @Wandy ?

Comment: docker logs $PEER_CONTAINER_ID. you can get it.

Comment: so there's a couple of different containers running during that example. 
When I call invoke js
1. the ca.example.com container's logs do not change
2. the dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0 logs do not change
3. the orderer logs do and there is this interesting piece of info 
`2018-05-09 13:24:15.560 UTC [grpc] Printf -> DEBU 435 transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 172.18.0.3:7050->10.0.2.2:62390: read: connection reset by peer`

Comment: From your log, I can see the transaction is good. I guess it is the client code, which misconfig the eventhub.

Comment: thanks @Wandy yeah I hope so! I know they just added channel event hub recently, so maybe the example needs updated to use that instead?